# How to set double-spaced text (1-inch margins, 12-point font)?

Tags: formatting, margins, line-spacing

How to set double-spaced text (1-inch margins, 12-point font) in Overleaf?
Currently, my text style is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\title{Replication pdf}
\author{yz}
\date{April 2020}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}    % <--- 12pt font
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}% <--- 1 in margin
\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespace                      % <--- double space

\usepackage{lipsum}
\title{Replication pdf}
\author{yz}
\date{April 2020}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]